# PDFLaTeX and LIVE finished with exit code 1

Tags: pdftex, kile

```latex
\documentclass{article}[12pt]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[a4paper, bindingoffset=0.5in, left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entrynumberformat=\entrywithprefix{\chaptername}]{tocline}{chapter}
\newcommand*\entrywithprefix[2]{#1~#2}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

\title{Die Entwicklung des Glücksspiels in mathematischer Hinsicht}
\author{Daniel Ferenczi}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\graphicspath{{/home/data/daniel/iskolaimunka/VWA/figures}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
    \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\\[2mm]
    \begin{minipage}{14.65cm}
        \normalfont \sffamily
        \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{institution.pdf}\raggedright
        \begin{minipage}{13.1cm}
            \normalfont \sffamily
            \mbox{\Large\bfseries {BG/BRG KIRCHENGASSE}}\raggedleft\\
        \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
    \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\\[2mm]
    \vfill
    \normalfont \sffamily
    {\Huge \bfseries Die Entwicklung des Glücksspiels in mathematischer Hinsicht}\\[5mm]
    {\huge Vorwissenschaftliche Arbeit}
    \vfill
    verfasst von\\
    Daniel Ferenczi\\
    BG/BRG Kirchengasse\\[10mm]
    Betreuer: Markus Sölkner\\[5mm]
    2024/02/TT
\end{center}
\normalsize
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\hfill
\newpage

\section*{Vorwort}
Glück. Darum geht es im Glücksspiel. Und in dieser Arbeit. Man geht durch die Straßen Wiens. Zum Glück ist nicht Viel los. Stöbert in Geschäften. Zum Glück gibt es hier und da mal einen Rabatt. Dies sind zwei Beispiele aus dem Alltag wo die meisten Menschen typisch: ``zum Glück" sagen würden. Doch was ist Glück eigentlich? Ist es eine übernatürliche Kraft? Oder der Würfel Gottes?\\
Einstein sagte mal: ''Gott würfelt nicht." Er hat dies eigentlich auf Physikalische Abläufe innerhalb eines Atoms bezogen, dennoch stimmt es auch in den obigen Beispielen. Es hat einen Grund warum Wien zu dem Zeitpunkt nicht mit Touristen überflutet ist. Genauso hat es auch Gründe warum manche Produkte im Markt gerade einen Rabatt bekommen und welche nicht. Das ist nicht Glückssache. Dieses Missverständnis und einige spannende Fragen um das Thema Glück möchte ich mit dieser Arbeit aufklären.\\
Und so stellt sich die Frage was das ``\textit{echte}" Glück ist. Definiert man das Wort \textit{echt}, so bekommt man: wahr, wirklich, real. Also das ''reale`` Glück sieht man am besten vielleicht am meist bekannten Glücksspiel, dem Lotto. Es ist reiner Zufall wie viele Zahlen man richtig tippt. Und so kommen wir zum ersten Mathematischen synonym von Glück: Zufall. Und auch Folgendes ist nicht zufällig:\\
In vielen Filmen sieht man Glücksspiel. Ob nur eine Runde Poker gespielt, ein Glücksrad gedreht, oder gewettet wird. Meist wird es dargestellt wie eine pure Goldmine. Der ``legale” Weg schnell reich zu werden.\\
Dies hat mit der Glücksspielindustrie zu tun. Die Lobbyisten und Konzerne stecken enorme Energien und Geld in viele Filme, um Casinos positiv darstellen zu lassen. Ist das aber wirklich so? Kann eine Nacht in Las Vegas zu Millionen von Dollar führen? Warum ist in Las Vegas heute eines der größten Glücksspielzentren der Welt? Und wo hat das Ganze begonnen? Und welche Rolle spielte Mathematik in der Entwicklung?\\
Die meisten Menschen wissen was Glücksspiele sind. Dennoch, hier eine kurze Erklärung: Glücksspiele sind ''Spiele``, die kaum, oder gar nicht durch (strategischen) Entscheidungen beeinflusst werden können. Und für diese Aussage würden mich manche ja für blöd halten. Warum? Poker. Das ist ein Spiel wo viele denken, es gäbe strategische Entscheidungen um den Lauf des Spiels verändern. Nein. Das ist reine psychologische ''Kriegsführung``. Welche Karten aufgedeckt werden, also das ''Glück``, werden nicht beeinflusst. Also kann man kurz sagen: Glücksspiele sind Spiele die nicht durch (strategischen) Entscheidungen beeinflusst werden können. Wo sehen wir aber solche Phenomäne?\\
Zum Beispiel hat das Wetter mit Glück zu tun. Es ist zwar ein wenig vorberechenbar, aber so ist es mit allen Wahrscheinlichkeiten. Ein anderes Beispiel für Glück im  ''Alltag`` ist das Glücksspiel. Wie vorhin schon erklärt kann man es nicht beeinflussen welche Karte als nächstes aufgedeckt, oder in welche Schale die Kugel beim Roulettetisch fallen wird. Zufall. Und so kommt man schon an bei Pierre-Simon Laplac, einem Mathematiker, der sich intensiv mit Glück auseinandergesetzt hat. Er ist einer der vielen die versucht haben Methoden zu der Berechnung des Zufalles zu finden. Er war aber nicht der einzige. Auch Pierre de Fermat und Blaise Pascale haben sich mit dem Zufall beschäftigt. Doch ist es ihm oder anderen gelungen? Und wie hat sich das auf das Glücksspiel ausgewirkt? Um das zu sehen müssen wir uns das Mathematische Glück und ihre Geschichte betrachten.
\pagebreak

\section*{Abstract}
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
\vfill
\newpage

\section{Die Geschichte Des Glücksspiels}
Glücksspiele sind teilweise älter als unser Kalender. Schon im antiken Griechenland, Ägypten und Rom wurden Spilele mit hohem Glücksanteil gespielt. Damals eher als Entfesselung aus dem Alltag, und Einkommensquelle, heute eher als Wirtschaftszweig gesehen, hat sich Glücksspiel in ihrer Art und Erscheinung viel verändert. Aber nicht nur das Glücksspiel veränderte sich selber, aber auch viele mathematische Entdeckungen entwickelten das Glücksspiel, und die Gesetztesgebung auf solche Zeitvertreibe bezogen ganz besonders. Dieses Kapitel beschäftigt sich mit der Entwicklung des Glücksspiels in bezug auf Gesellschaft und Zeitalter. Jedoch muss man beachten, dass die Moderne, oder Neuzeit des Glücksspiels erst mit den Spielautomaten begann.

\subsection{Glücksspiel in der Antike}
Die antike Zeit wurde geprägt durch das misteriöse Darstellen von Zufall und Mathematik im allgemeinen. Man versuchte das Göttliche in Zahlen und deren Zusammenhängen zu finden. Nicht anders wurde dies in bezug auf Zufall auch vermutet. Der einzige Unterschied den es zwischen der Sichtweise auf das zufällige und der Sichtweise auf andere Kapiteln der Mathematik gab war, dass das Glück als göttlicher Wille gesehen worden ist. Antike Völker prägten den Glauben an Gott viel mehr als man es sich vorstellen mag.\footnote{''Griechenland``} Viele wichtige Entscheidungen wurden durch Glück, beziehungsweise, damals Gottes Hand gedacht, entschieden. Man vermutete dies sei gerecht weil das Willen der Götter den Zufall beeinflussten. Und so war auch das Glücksspielen eine Erscheinung die man heute zwar mit Verschiedenen mathematischen Modellen zwar darstellen kann, in der Antike jedoch gar nicht erklären wollte. Man hatte angst dies auch nur zu bezweifeln, da man Angst vor dem Zorn der Götter hatte. Für das Glück waren im antiken Griechenland der Hirtengott Pan und der Götterbote Hermes zuständig.\\
Häufig spielte man Würfelspiele, mit würfeln aus Elfenbein, Kopf oder Zahl, Kartenspiele, oder schloss wetten, zum Beispiel bei Pferderennen. Zugang zu Glücksspielen hatte jeder. Von Sklaven, über Bauern, bis hin zu den Adeligen. Natürlch konnte sich die Bäuerliche Schicht damals kein Teures Equipment leisten. Zum Spielen reichte lediglich ein Spielgitter, welches in den Boden geritzt wurde. Zugänglichkeit bedeutete jedoch nicht, dass das Glücksspielen auch legal war. Im antiken Rom gab es sogar seit dem 3. JH. v. Chr. ein Würfelspielverbot. Zwei Jahrhunderte später folgten weitere solcher verbote. Vor allem wurden diese Verbote von der Gesetzgebung im antiken Rom geprägt. Hier durfte man nur zu ''Saturnalien`` (Weihnachten) spielen. Dies hielt aber nicht davon ab diesem hobby auch zu anderen tagen im Jahr nachzugehen. Hierbei ging es nicht nur um Götter sondern auch um Geld. Oft verwendete Einsätze waren Muscheln, es war jedoch nicht ungewöhnlich, dass manche Menschen ihr ganzes Hab und Gut verwetteten. Spielsucht existirte damals schon in einer sehr ähnlichen Form wie Heute. Selbst den Herrschern blieb diese Art von Vergnügen nicht erspart. Kaiser Claudius war selbst sehr fastziniert von einem Vorgänger des Backgammon. \footnote{''Antikes Glücksspiel``}$^,$\footnote{''Glücksspiel im laufe der Geschichte``}

\subsection{Glücksspiel im Mittelalter}
Verbote im Glücksspiel ziehen sich durch ihre ganze Geschichte. Nicht anders war dies auch im Mittelalter wo die Kirche das Glücksspiel versuchte sehr stark zu reduzieren. Trotzdem hat vor allem die Adleige Schicht sehr gerne und viel gespielt. Dies bekräftigten Taten wie die Verfügung von König Richard Löwenherz, die besagte, dass Glückspiel nur Ritter oder Höherrangige spielen durften. Dies hielt das gemeine Volk aber nicht davon ab selber dieses Hobby zu betreiben. Würfelspiele waren am beliebtesten, Kartenspiele waren aber auch nicht selten anzutreffen. Obwohl aus dem Mittelalter recht wenige Aufzeichnungen übrig geblieben sind, kann man das wort Casino zum Beispiel auf den Adel der damaligen Zeit zurückführen. Casino ist das Diminuitiv vom Italiänischen wort für Haus ''Casa`` und vedeutet nichts anderes als Häuschen. Diese ''Häuschen`` haben sich im späten Mittelalter, 16. und 17. Jahrhundert, in den Zentren Italiens, entwickelt. Hier trafen sich verschiedenste Menschen und Verantalteten Glücksspiele. Das erste Offizielle Casino entstand im Venedig des 16. Jahrhunderts, wo man schon damals einen Festen Dresscode und etwas an Kleingeld notwendig hatte um spielen zu können. Diese Art von Vergnügung wurde schnell in ganz Europa beliebt. Jedoch nicht immer zu hundert Prozent Legalisiert. Die Gründung des deutschen Kaiserreichs brachte wieder Verbote mit sich. Und so war am ende des 18. Jahrhunderts wieder jegliches Glücksspiel verboten.\footnote{''Glücksspiel im laufe der Geschichte``}

\subsection{Die Moderne des Glücksspiels}
Die Neuzeit des Glücksspiels dotiert man auf die Entwicklung erster Spielautomaten. Diese erschienen erstmals am ende des 18. Jahrhunderts in Amerika.
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.2\textwidth}
    \vspace{-10pt}
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Libertybell.png}
    \caption{Liberty Bell}
\end{wrapfigure}
Diese Automaten waren von der Funktionsweise rein Mechanisch und boten den Spielern wenig Abwechslung. Nichtsdestotrotz war die Beliebtheit dieser Maschienen groß, was dafür sorgte, dass die Weiterentwicklung dieser Geräte zügig voranging. Dennoch veränderte sich nicht alles. Noch heute sind Nostalgische Elemente aus damaliger Zeit auf den modernen Spielautomaten zu finden. Ein solches Ist zum Beispiel der ''Liberty Bell``. Dies war damals wie heute ein Gewinnsymbol. Der grund sie als Gewinnsymbol zu nutzen ist naheliegend. Sie wurde Geläutet als 1752 in Pensylvania die Amerikanische Unabhängigkeitserklärung unterzeichnet worden ist. Automaten waren auch unter dem Namen ''Einarmiger Bandit`` Bekannt, da sie durch einem Hebel auf der Seite betätigt worden sind, und den Spielern das Geld aus der Tasche gezogen haben. Dies hing mit der Auszalungsate der Automaten zusammen, die sehr gering war, und so hatten Menschen sehr oft das Gefühl, dass sie bestohlen worden. Aber auch das ist Vergangenheit. Heute haben Automaten Qualitäten, die das Suchtpotenzial und den Spielspaß erhöhen.\footnote{''Glücksspiel im laufe der Geschichte``}

\subsection{Glücksspiel Heute}
Heutzutage versteht man unter Glücksspiel meist nicht mehr Würfelspiele wie man sie in der Antike gekannt hat. Und stellt man sich als Glücksspiel Kartenspiele und Roulett vor dann irrt man sich. Denn auch Casinos Rutschen aus der Mode. Die Bequemlichkeit der Menschen übertrifft jeden anderen Reiz. So muss man nicht einmal mehr ein Casino besuchen um sich zugang zu Glücksspielen zu erschaffen. Dafür reicht eine herkömmliche Internetverbindung, und schon kann man jegliche Arten von Glücksspielen genießen.\footnote{''Glücksspiel im laufe der Geschichte``} Schaut man sich aber vorerst moderne Casinos an, so sieht man überall nur Blinkende Maschienen, hin und wieder einen Black Jack tisch, und selten Roulett. Dies Kan man durch die optimalisierung der Software der Glücksspielautomaten erklären. Hierbei spielt mittlerweile auch Künstliche Intelligenz eine große Rolle. Damit beschäftigt sich aber ein anderes Kapitel dieser Arbeit\footnote{siehe Kapitel ...}. In einer digitalisierten Welt übernimmt, auch wie in vielen anderen Branchen, die Online Welt das Sagen. Der Grund dafür ist aber nicht nur der Mensch selbst. Online Casinos bieten mehr auswahl an spielen, und heben eher die Resoursen höhere boni als Landbasierte Casinos anzubieten, da viele Betriebskosten wegfallen.\footnote{der-kultur-blog.de die geschichte des glücksspiels} Dadurch erhöht sich teilweise der Gewinn der Betriebe, andererseits das Entwicklungs-potenzial. Denn auch wenn Glückspielautomaten oder Glücksspiele keine Wissenschaft sind, sitzen Tausende an Psychologie-experten hinter diesen Konzernen und suchen danach wie man von den Menschen noch mehr und noch effizienter Geld entziehen kann. Begünstigend kommt dazu, dass Künstliche Intelligenz personalisierte Profile erstellt und die Spiele anpasst. Dazu führend dass das Suchtpotenzial und die Verluste an der Spielerseite steigen.
\vfill
\newpage

\section{Die Geschichte der Beschreibung von zufälligen Erreignissen}
Das berechnen des Glücks ist eine sehr junge Wissenschaft. Der erste Mathematiker der sich mit diesem Kapitel der Mathematik auseinandergesetzt hat, war Girolamo Cardano, ein italiäner, der von 1501 bis 1576 gelebt hat. So richtig Hat die Wahrwscheinlichkeitsrechnung erst im 17. Jahrhundert seine Bedeutung erlangt mit dem Briefwechsel zwischen Fermat und seinem Schüler, Pascal. Im gegensatz dazu sind Algebra und Geometrie schon Jahrtausende alt, sie waren schon im antiken Griechenland von Philosophen erforscht worden.

\subsection{Pioniere der Wahrwscheinlichkeitsrechnung}
Wie schon erwähnt war der erste Mathematiker der sich mit dem Bererchnen des Glücks beschäftigt hat, der italiäner  Girolamo Cardano. 1565 verfasste er das Werk namens ''Liber de Ludo Aleae`` (Buch vom Würfelspiel), welches erst fast hundert Jahre später, 1663, veröffentlicht wurde. Dieser Text beschrieb aber nicht alles korrekter Weise, dennoch hatten Cardano und sein Helfer, Niccoló Tartagilia (1506?-1559) wichtige Grundbausteine der Kombinatorik gesetzt, wie die Gesetze zur Addition von Wahrscheinlichkeiten.\footnote{Spektrum.de/rezension}\\
Galileo Galilei (1564-1642) war der nächste der die Wahrwscheinlichkeitsrechnung geprägt hat. Einen kleinen Teil seiner werke widmete er sogar dem Würfelwurf und dessen Mathematik.\\
So richtig zum leben erwäckt wurde die Berechnung von zufälligen Erreignissen aber erst im 17. Jahrhundert, durch Pierre de Fermat (1601-1665) und Blaise Pascal (1623-1662). Blaise Pascal Schrieb eines Tages einen Brief an seinen Lehrer Pierre de Fermat. Dies war der Wahre beginn der Wahrwscheinlichkeitsrechnung. Der Brief behandelte Ein Problem, welches Huygens später auch behandelte.\footnote{Handbook of Probability S.4}
\begin{quote}
  \textit''Ich konnte Ihnen mit der letzten Postsendung nicht alle meine Gedanken bezüglich des Spielabbruchproblems darlegen, und ich habe sogar einigen Widerwillen, dies zu tun, aus Furcht, dass sabei diese wunderbare Übereinstimmung, die zwischen uns war und die mir so Teuer war, sich aufzuheben beginnt; denn ich befürchte, dass wir über diesen Gegenstand verschiedener Ansicht sind. Ich will Ihnen meine Argumente darlegen, und tun Sie mir den Gefallen, mich zu verbessern, wenn ich irre, oder mich zu bestärken, wen ich recht habe. Ich bitte Sie darum inständig und aufrichtig, denn ich werde mich nur im Recht fühlen, wenn sie meiner Ansicht sind.`` \footnote{Quelle Brief}
\end{quote}                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Pascals allererste begegnung mit der Wahrwscheinlichkeitsrechnung war die Lösung der Frage von Antoine Gombaud, Chevalier de Méré, ein damals bekannter Glücksspieler, über die chanchen eine Doppel-sechs beim Würfelspiel zu würfeln, zu disskutieren. Dies ist heute unter dem Namen ''Méré-problem`` oder ''Würfelproblem`` bekannt.\\
Ein weiteres Problem welches als Meilenstein der Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie gesehen werden kann, ist eines das 1656 von Christiaan Huygens (1629-1695) im Buch: ''Van Rekeningh in Spelen van Geluck`` (Der Wert aller Chanchen im Glücksspiel) behandelt wurde. Hierbei ging es um die Verteilung der gewonnenen Summe, bei bestimmten Punkteständen, unter den Spielern. Dieses Werk war das Erste welches, von Niederländisch, auf Latein und Englisch übersetzt worden ist.\\
James Bernoulli (1654-1704) auch bekannt als James \rom{1} da es mehrere James Bernoullis gab. Er schreib die erste bedeutende Abhandlung der Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie ''Ars Conjectadi``, welche 2005 von Edith Sylla neu publiziert wurde unter dem Namen ''The Art of Conjecturing, together with Letter to a Friend on Sets in Court Tennis``(Die Kunst des Vermutens, zusammen mit einem Brief An einen Freund über sätze im Court Tennis), und 1713 posthum veröffentlicht wurde. Das Werk enthielt bemerkenswerte ergebnisse in bereich der Kombinatorik, Summen, und Integral im bezug zur Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie. Außerdem ergänzte es werke von Fermat, Pascal, und Huygens. Eine weitere auffällige eigenschaft der Publikation war der rigorose Beweis des ''shchwachen Gesetzes der Großen Zahlen``: \[\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|\bar{X}\_n-\mu|>\epsilon)=1\]\\
Im 18. Jahrhundert wurde das Buch ''The Doctrine of Chances`` (Die Lehre von den Wahrscheinlichkeiten) von Abraham De Moivre (1667-1754) publiziert. Damit leistete De Moivre grundlegende Arbeit in bezug zum Problem ''Ruin des Spielers`` (das verlieren des Letzten Kapitals und somit die Möglichkeit weiterzuspielen). Sein wichtigstes Ergebnis bestand darin, eine Annäherung an die symmetrische  Binomialverteilung zu finden, die er als eine Annäherung an die Normalverteilung darstellen könnte. Dieses Ergebnis läuft in der modernen Terminologie auf einen Beweis hinaus welcher besagt, dass die symmetrische Binomialverteilung durch die Normalverteilung angenähert werden kann.\\
Ein weiterer Pionier der Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie war Leonhard Euler (1701-1783), welcher viele seiner Beiträge zur Wahrwscheinlichkeitsberechnung, auf einer Untersuchung der Genueser Lotterie basierte. Insbesondere Beschäftigte er sich mit dem Problem der Rencontres, wo Euler zeigen konnte dass die Wahrscheinlichkeit, wenn sich zwei Personen gegenseitig von $1-n$ nummerierte Karten zeigen, dass sie einander gleichzeitig die gleiche Karte zeigen, den Wert $1/e$ annähert wenn \[\lim_{n\to\infty} \] ist.\\

\subsection{Das Glück mathematisch beschrieben}
Wenn man sagt, dass Glück nicht beeinflussbar ist, wie kann man das dann Mathematisch darstellen? Und kann man damit überhaupt ''klassisch`` rechnen?\\
Bevor man diese Fragen beantworten kann, muss man die Begriffe aus dem Glück mathematisch definieren, beziehungsweise die Alltagsbegriffe in die Sprache der Mathematik übersetzten.\\
Statt Glück verwendet die Mathematik den Begriff ''Zufall``. Um einen Zufall zu berechnen, rechnet man mit ''Wahrscheinlichkeiten``. Wie viel Chance hat es, dass es morgen regnen wird? Die Menge aller möglichen Ergebnisse ist die Ergebniss-menge \[S=\left\{X_1;X_2;...;X_n\right\}\] Was in diesem Fall: \[S=\left\{S;R\right\}\]\footnote{Introduction to probability Models} ist, $S$ für Sonnenschein und $R$ für Regen. Die Wahrscheinlichkeit für das eintreffen von $R$ beträgt null wen es gar nicht wahrscheinlich ist dass es regnen wird. Ist es aber sicher dass es morgen regnen wird, ist die Wahrscheinlichkeit für das Eintreffen von $R$ eins. Bei einem Münzwurf beträgt die Wahrscheinlichkeit $P(x)=0.5$ für beide Ereignisse, Kopf, wie Zahl. Von einem ''Versuch`` redet man dann, wenn man zum Beispiel einen Würfel, oder eine Münze wirft. Man ''testet`` die Wahrscheinlichkeit. Bei einem Würfel- oder Münzwurf handelt es sich sogar um einen ''Laplac'schen Versuch``\footnote{Mathebuch 6. Klasse}, da jeder Ausgang des Versuchs gleich wahrscheinlich ist.  Verschiedene Versuche müssen mit verschiedenen Verteilungen berechnet und modelliert werden, da sich Roulett, ein Münzwurf, Lotto oder  Black Jack ganz anders verhalten. Das Ergebnis eines Versuchs ein ''Versuchsausgang`` oder ''Ereignis``$X$. Das heißt, ein Zufallsversuch hat die Wahrscheinlichkeit $P(X_n)$ den einen bestimmten $n$-ten Versuchsausgang zu produzieren. Wobei gilt: \[0\leq P(X)\leq1\]. Versuche haben aber nicht nur ein Ergebnis und dieses Ergebnis eine Wahrscheinlichkeit $P(X)$, sondern auch einen Erwartungswert: \[E(X)=\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_n}{n}\] Dieser beschreibt das durchschnittliche Ergebnis des Versuchs. Wenn man jetzt einen Würfelwurf als Versuch hernimmt, und einsetzt sieht das dann wie folgt aus: \[E(X)=\frac{1+2+3+4+5+6}{6}=3,5\] Noch einen wichtigen Wert darf man nicht vergessen wenn man mit Wahrscheinlichkeiten rechnet. Dies ist die Varianz. Sie beschriebt wie weit unsere Ergebnisse von unserem Erwartungswert gestreut sind. Die formel dafür lautet: \[\sigma^2=\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}(x_n-\bar{x})^2}{n}\] Wobei \[\sum^n_{i=1}(x_n-\bar{x})^2\] die Summe aller Ereignisse minus den Duschschnitt der ereignisse zum Quadrat ist. Setzt man wieder einen Würfelwurf ein bekommt man folgende Gleichung: \[\sigma^2=\frac{\sum^6_{i=1}(x_6-\frac{1+2+3+4+5+6}{6})^2}{6}=\frac{17,5}{6}\approx2,92\] Diese Formel nochmal umgeformt bekommt man die Standardabweichung:\[\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}(x_n-\bar{x})^2}{n}}\] Sie beschreiibt nun nicht mehr das Maß der Streuung, sondern die durchschnittliche Abweichung des Ergebnisses vom Erwartungswert. Und wenn man wieder einsetzt sieht man gleich, dass wenn man die Varianz berechnet hat, die Standardabweichung nichts anderes ist als: \[\sqrt{\sigma^2}=\sqrt{\frac{\sum^6_{i=1}(x_6-\frac{1+2+3+4+5+6}{6})^2}{6}}=\sqrt{\frac{17,5}{6}}\approx1,71\] Um jetzt verschiedene Informationen aus einer bestimmten Datenmenge herauslesen zu können, verwendet man verschiedene Formeln, in der Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie Verteilungen genannt.
{%
    \newcommand{\mc}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \mc{1}{c}{\textbf{Verteilung}} & \mc{1}{c}{\textbf{X zählt}} & \mc{1}{c}{\textbf{P(X)}}\\
        Binomialverteilung & Erfolge bei $n$ fixen Versuchen & $\binom{n}{k}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$\\
        Poissonverteilung & Ankünfte in einer fixen Zeitspanne & $\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}$\\
        Geometrische Verteilung & Versuche bis zum ersten Erfolg & $p(1-p)^{x-1}$\\
        Negative Binomialverteilung & Versuche bis zum $k$-ten Erfolg & $\binom{x-1}{k-1}p^k(1-p)^{x-k}$\\
        Hypergeometrische Verteilung & Elemente in einer Stichprobe\footnote[56]{Ohne Zurücklegen} & $frac{\binom{M}{x}\binom{N-M}{n-x}}{\binom{N}{n}}$
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
}%

\subsection{Entwicklung mathemathischer Methoden}
Ausdrücke wie diese sind das Ergebnis Jahrhunderte langer Arbeit. Einige der Wissenschaftler und Mathematiker, die zur Entwicklung der in Unterkapitel 2.2 (Das Glück mathematisch beschrieben) wurden im Unterkapitel 2.1 (Pioniere der Wahrwscheinlichkeitsrechnung) schon erwähnt. Hier soll es aber nicht um die Personen gehen, sondern viel eher um die Entwicklung der Mathemathik. Um Rechenwege und Herleitungen der Methoden, die heutzutage in der Wahrwscheinlichkeitsberechnung gang und gebe sind.\\
Girolamo Cardano kam 1565 zum Schluss, dass wenn man eine Chance von $\frac{1}{c}$ hat, dass ein Ereignis eintrift, und $n$ anzahl an Versuchen durchführt, wird man das Ereignis $\frac{n}{c}$ mal erhalten.\\
Wärenddessen findet in Frankreich der Briefwechsel Zwischen Pascal und Fermat, über das Abgebrochene Spiel Problem, statt. Hierbei handelt es sich um folgende Situation: Man stelle sich vor 2 Spieler:innen spielen einen Würfelspiel. Die Person die höher würfelt gewinnt. Aber das Spiel wird vor Spielende abgebrochen. Wie werden Gewinne verteilt? Wenn der Punktestand 1 zu 1 beträgt werden die Gewinne gleichmäßig verteilt. Steht es 2 zu 2 ist das auch eine gleichmäßige Verteilung. Aber was passiert wenn es 2 zu 1 steht? Die person mit einem Punkt hat auch noch Chancen das Spiel zu gewinnen und somit auch den Einsatz. Die Methode die Pascal nutzt, ist rein logisches Kombinieren. Dabei stellt er sich die verschiedenen Ausgänge der nächsten Runden vor. Wenn die zwei Spieler:innen nur bis 3 punkten gespielt hätten ist es einfach. In der Nebenstehenden Grafik sind die Möglichen Ausgänge dargestellt. 
\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3585]{Screenshot_2024-01-05_11-43-18.png}\\
    \centering
\end{figure}
Was man sieht sind die möglichen Wege, die zu einem Gewinn der beiden Spieler:innen führen. Folgende sind zu beachten:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Spieler:in 1 gewinnt die nächste Runde, es steht 3 zu 1 und Spieler:in 1 gewinnt den Einsatz
    \item Spieler:in 2 gewinnt die nächste runde, es steht 2 zu 2 und das Spiel wird fortgeführt
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Spieler:in 1 gewinnt die 2. Runde, es steht 3 zu 2 und Spieler:in 1 gewinnt den Einsatz
        \item Spieler:in 2 gewinnt die 2. Runde, es steht 2 zu 3 und Spieler:in 2 gewinnt den Einsatz
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
Jetzt muss man nur noch schauen wie wahrscheinlich ist es dass Spieler:in 1, beziehungsweise 2 gewinnt. Dazu nimmt man alle ''günstigen`` Ereignisse und dividiert sie durch die ''möglichen`` Ereignisse. Sieht dann wie Folgt aus:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Die Wahrscheinlichkeit dass Spieler:in 1 gewinnt:\[P(S_1)=\frac{2}{3}\] denn es gab 3 mögliche Wege, sie gewinnt davon bei 2.
    \item Die Wahrscheinlichkeit dass Spieler:in 2 gewinnt:\[P(S_2)=\frac{1}{3}\] denn es gab 3 mögliche Wege, sie gewinnt davon bei 1.
\end{itemize}
Auf diese Methode ist man damals aber nicht gekommen. Am ehersten konnte Girolamo Cardano dieses Problem Lösen. Dies findet man in seinem ''Buch vom Würfelspiel``.\footnote{Keith Delvin} Doch woran leigt es, ein mit heutigem Auge so einfaches Problem, Wissenschaftler damals kaum lösen konnten? Dies kann man mit zwei grundsetztlichen Gründen erklären:
\begin{itemize}
    \item[1] Es war ein völlig neues Konzept die Zukunft berechnen zu wollen.
    \item[2] Die verwendeten Begrifflichkeiten erschwerten das Verständniss. Anstatt von Wahrscheinlichkeit, verwendete man damals ''Zufall`` oder ''Anzahl der Gelegenheiten``.\footnote{Keith delvin 20}
\end{itemize}

\section{Glücksspiele Modellieren}

%\bibliography

\end{document}
```

Why do I get: PDFLaTeX finished with exit code 1? There should be no reason for that. Only \hbox badboxes, but no errors warnings or whatsoever.
PLS help!!!

Comment: Show the log file

Comment: What do you mean with LIVE? Please explain!

Comment: `\textit''` produces an italic apostrophe next to a roman one, is that intended?

Comment: Please do *not* just include your entire document. It's unreasonable to expect us to read it all to find your error—not to mention that we can't compile it anyway because we don't have your image files. Please follow the guidelines for a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/270231).

Comment: I've fixed the markdown. Now, the class you are using is shown. But the problem is still not reproducible. If I replace the images by `example-image` to make the example complete, there are no errors. However, `\documentclass{article}[12pt]` should be replaced by `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`. And your `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[…]{…}{chapter}` is useless, because `article` does not have chapters.

Comment: It's pointless to load the `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages without a suitable option. Do give `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` a try.

Comment: Off-topic: You should *not* use `\\ ` for paragraphs. Use either `\par` or simply an empty line. And IMHO all your `\pagebreak` should be either `\newpage` or `\clearpage`. And your quotes are not correct, neither for English nor for German. In German typography you should use something like the `babel` quotes ```"`bla"'``` to get `„bla”` or like `»bla«` or better use [package `csquotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes).

Comment: For crying out loud, in a German-language document please use the original German and not the anglicized form of Bernoulli's given name: Jakob, *not* James.

Comment: LIVE is the Live preview by Kile provided for beginners in this matter, to see the outcome immediately as you type.

Answer (score 2):

> There should be no reason for [error messages]

Actually, there are quite a few minor mistakes, and a number of major mistakes, in your document, beginning with `\documentclass{article}[12pt]`, which has got to be `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`.

It's an out-and-out mistake to use `\\` to create paragraph breaks. You should be using either `\par` or, better still, a blank line to create paragraph breaks. No exceptions. No way, no how.

Somewhat amusingly (perplexingly?), you consistently get the use of opening and closing quotes wrong: It should be

```
``Wort''
```

rather than

```
''Wort``
```

Actually, given that the document is in German, you ought to use either German- or French-style quotation marks ("Gänsefüßchen" and "guillemets", resp.) One way to do so is to load the `csquotes` package with the option `german=quotes` or `german=guillemets`, resp., and to use the `\enquote` command.

Do please also fix the uses of the vowels `ä` and `e`, as their incorrect use makes for highly distracting reading. And, do please find a way to correct the numerous inconsistencies in uppercasing and lowercasing words.

Incidentally, the weak law of large numbers is generally stated as

```
\lim_{n\to\infty} P(|\bar{X}_n-\mu|>\epsilon) = 0
```

rather than as

```
\lim_{n\to\infty} P(|\bar{X}_n-\mu|>\epsilon) = 1
```

The following is a screenshot of the first page (other than titlepage stuff) of the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,demo]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper, bindingoffset=0.5in, margin=1in,
 footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
%\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[ entrynumberformat=\entrywithprefix{\chaptername}]{tocline}{chapter}
\newcommand*\entrywithprefix[2]{#1~#2}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

\title{Die Entwicklung des Glücksspiels in mathematischer Hinsicht}
\author{Daniel Ferenczi}

%\renewcommand\contentsname{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\graphicspath{{/home/data/daniel/iskolaimunka/VWA/figures}}
\newcommand{\mc}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\\[2mm]
\begin{minipage}{14.65cm}
\normalfont \sffamily
\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{institution.pdf}
%\raggedright
\begin{minipage}{13.1cm}
\normalfont \sffamily
\hfill \Large\bfseries BG/BRG KIRCHENGASSE
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\\[2mm]
\vfill
\normalfont \sffamily
{\Huge \bfseries Die Entwicklung des Glücksspiels in mathematischer Hinsicht\par}

\vspace{5mm}
{\huge Vorwissenschaftliche Arbeit\par}
\vfill
verfasst von

Daniel Ferenczi

BG/BRG Kirchengasse\\[10mm]
Betreuer: Markus Sölkner\\[5mm]
2024/02/TT
\end{center}
\normalsize
\end{titlepage}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\hfill
\newpage

\section*{Vorwort}

Glück. Darum geht es im Glücksspiel. Und in dieser Arbeit. Man geht durch die Straßen Wiens. Zum Glück ist nicht Viel los. Stöbert in Geschäften. Zum Glück gibt es hier und da mal einen Rabatt. Dies sind zwei Beispiele aus dem Alltag wo die meisten Menschen typisch: \enquote{zum Glück} sagen würden. Doch was ist Glück eigentlich? Ist es eine übernatürliche Kraft? Oder der Würfel Gottes?

Einstein sagte mal: \enquote{Gott würfelt nicht.} Er hat dies eigentlich auf Physikalische Abläufe innerhalb eines Atoms bezogen, dennoch stimmt es auch in den obigen Beispielen. Es hat einen Grund warum Wien zu dem Zeitpunkt nicht mit Touristen überflutet ist. Genauso hat es auch Gründe warum manche Produkte im Markt gerade einen Rabatt bekommen und welche nicht. Das ist nicht Glückssache. Dieses Missverständnis und einige spannende Fragen um das Thema Glück möchte ich mit dieser Arbeit aufklären.\par Und so stellt sich die Frage was das \enquote{\textit{echte}} Glück ist. Definiert man das Wort \textit{echt}, so bekommt man: wahr, wirklich, real. Also das \enquote{reale} Glück sieht man am besten vielleicht am meist bekannten Glücksspiel, dem Lotto. Es ist reiner Zufall wie viele Zahlen man richtig tippt. Und so kommen wir zum ersten Mathematischen synonym von Glück: Zufall. Und auch Folgendes ist nicht zufällig: In vielen Filmen sieht man Glücksspiel. Ob nur eine Runde Poker gespielt, ein Glücksrad gedreht, oder gewettet wird. Meist wird es dargestellt wie eine pure Goldmine. Der \enquote{legale} Weg schnell reich zu werden.

Dies hat mit der Glücksspielindustrie zu tun. Die Lobbyisten und Konzerne stecken enorme Energien und Geld in viele Filme, um Casinos positiv darstellen zu lassen. Ist das aber wirklich so? Kann eine Nacht in Las Vegas zu Millionen von Dollar führen? Warum ist in Las Vegas heute eines der größten Glücksspielzentren der Welt? Und wo hat das Ganze begonnen? Und welche Rolle spielte Mathematik in der Entwicklung?

Die meisten Menschen wissen was Glücksspiele sind. Dennoch, hier eine kurze Erklärung: Glücksspiele sind \enquote{Spiele,} die kaum, oder gar nicht durch (strategischen) Entscheidungen beeinflusst werden können. Und für diese Aussage würden mich manche ja für blöd halten. Warum? Poker. Das ist ein Spiel wo viele denken, es gäbe strategische Entscheidungen um den Lauf des Spiels verändern. Nein. Das ist reine psychologische \enquote{Kriegsführung.} Welche Karten aufgedeckt werden, also das \enquote{Glück,} werden nicht beeinflusst. Also kann man kurz sagen: Glücksspiele sind Spiele die nicht durch (strategischen) Entscheidungen beeinflusst werden können. Wo sehen wir aber solche Phenomäne?

Zum Beispiel hat das Wetter mit Glück zu tun. Es ist zwar ein wenig vorberechenbar, aber so ist es mit allen Wahrscheinlichkeiten. Ein anderes Beispiel für Glück im  \enquote{Alltag} ist das Glücksspiel. Wie vorhin schon erklärt kann man es nicht beeinflussen welche Karte als nächstes aufgedeckt, oder in welche Schale die Kugel beim Roulettetisch fallen wird. Zufall. Und so kommt man schon an bei Pierre-Simon Laplace, einem Mathematiker, der sich intensiv mit Glück auseinandergesetzt hat. Er ist einer der vielen die versucht haben Methoden zu der Berechnung des Zufalles zu finden. Er war aber nicht der einzige. Auch Pierre de Fermat und Blaise Pascale haben sich mit dem Zufall beschäftigt. Doch ist es ihm oder anderen gelungen? Und wie hat sich das auf das Glücksspiel ausgewirkt? Um das zu sehen müssen wir uns das Mathematische Glück und ihre Geschichte betrachten.

\pagebreak
\section*{Abstract}

\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
\vfill
\newpage

\section{Die Geschichte des Glücksspiels}

Glücksspiele sind teilweise älter als unser Kalender. Schon im antiken Griechenland, Ägypten und Rom wurden Spilele mit hohem Glücksanteil gespielt. Damals eher als Entfesselung aus dem Alltag, und Einkommensquelle, heute eher als Wirtschaftszweig gesehen, hat sich Glücksspiel in ihrer Art und Erscheinung viel verändert. Aber nicht nur das Glücksspiel veränderte sich selber, aber auch viele mathematische Entdeckungen entwickelten das Glücksspiel, und die Gesetztesgebung auf solche Zeitvertreibe bezogen ganz besonders. Dieses Kapitel beschäftigt sich mit der Entwicklung des Glücksspiels in bezug auf Gesellschaft und Zeitalter. Jedoch muss man beachten, dass die Moderne, oder Neuzeit des Glücksspiels erst mit den Spielautomaten begann.

\subsection{Glücksspiel in der Antike}

Die antike Zeit wurde geprägt durch das misteriöse Darstellen von Zufall und Mathematik im allgemeinen. Man versuchte das Göttliche in Zahlen und deren Zusammenhängen zu finden. Nicht anders wurde dies in bezug auf Zufall auch vermutet. Der einzige Unterschied den es zwischen der Sichtweise auf das zufällige und der Sichtweise auf andere Kapiteln der Mathematik gab war, dass das Glück als göttlicher Wille gesehen worden ist. Antike Völker prägten den Glauben an Gott viel mehr als man es sich vorstellen mag.\footnote{\enquote{Griechenland}} Viele wichtige Entscheidungen wurden durch Glück, beziehungsweise, damals Gottes Hand gedacht, entschieden. Man vermutete dies sei gerecht weil das Willen der Götter den Zufall beeinflussten. Und so war auch das Glücksspielen eine Erscheinung die man heute zwar mit Verschiedenen mathematischen Modellen zwar darstellen kann, in der Antike jedoch gar nicht erklären wollte. Man hatte angst dies auch nur zu bezweifeln, da man Angst vor dem Zorn der Götter hatte. Für das Glück waren im antiken Griechenland der Hirtengott Pan und der Götterbote Hermes zuständig.

Häufig spielte man Würfelspiele, mit würfeln aus Elfenbein, Kopf oder Zahl, Kartenspiele, oder schloss wetten, zum Beispiel bei Pferderennen. Zugang zu Glücksspielen hatte jeder. Von Sklaven, über Bauern, bis hin zu den Adeligen. Natürlch konnte sich die Bäuerliche Schicht damals kein Teures Equipment leisten. Zum Spielen reichte lediglich ein Spielgitter, welches in den Boden geritzt wurde. Zugänglichkeit bedeutete jedoch nicht, dass das Glücksspielen auch legal war. Im antiken Rom gab es sogar seit dem 3. JH. v.\,Chr. ein Würfelspielverbot. Zwei Jahrhunderte später folgten weitere solcher verbote. Vor allem wurden diese Verbote von der Gesetzgebung im antiken Rom geprägt. Hier durfte man nur zu \enquote{Saturnalien} (Weihnachten) spielen. Dies hielt aber nicht davon ab diesem hobby auch zu anderen tagen im Jahr nachzugehen. Hierbei ging es nicht nur um Götter sondern auch um Geld. Oft verwendete Einsätze waren Muscheln, es war jedoch nicht ungewöhnlich, dass manche Menschen ihr ganzes Hab und Gut verwetteten. Spielsucht existirte damals schon in einer sehr ähnlichen Form wie Heute. Selbst den Herrschern blieb diese Art von Vergnügen nicht erspart. Kaiser Claudius war selbst sehr fasziniert von einem Vorgänger des Backgammon. \footnote{\enquote{Antikes Glücksspiel}}$^,$\footnote{\enquote{Glücksspiel im Laufe der Geschichte}}


\subsection{Glücksspiel im Mittelalter}

Verbote im Glücksspiel ziehen sich durch ihre ganze Geschichte. Nicht anders war dies auch im Mittelalter wo die Kirche das Glücksspiel versuchte sehr stark zu reduzieren. Trotzdem hat vor allem die Adleige Schicht sehr gerne und viel gespielt. Dies bekräftigten Taten wie die Verfügung von König Richard Löwenherz, die besagte, dass Glückspiel nur Ritter oder Höherrangige spielen durften. Dies hielt das gemeine Volk aber nicht davon ab selber dieses Hobby zu betreiben. Würfelspiele waren am beliebtesten, Kartenspiele waren aber auch nicht selten anzutreffen. Obwohl aus dem Mittelalter recht wenige Aufzeichnungen übrig geblieben sind, kann man das Wort Casino zum Beispiel auf den Adel der damaligen Zeit zurückführen. Casino ist das Diminuitiv vom Italiänischen wort für Haus \enquote{Casa} und vedeutet nichts anderes als Häuschen. Diese \enquote{Häuschen} haben sich im späten Mittelalter, 16. und 17. Jahrhundert, in den Zentren Italiens, entwickelt. Hier trafen sich verschiedenste Menschen und Verantalteten Glücksspiele. Das erste Offizielle Casino entstand im Venedig des 16. Jahrhunderts, wo man schon damals einen Festen Dresscode und etwas an Kleingeld notwendig hatte um spielen zu können. Diese Art von Vergnügung wurde schnell in ganz Europa beliebt. Jedoch nicht immer zu hundert Prozent legalisiert. Die Gründung des deutschen Kaiserreichs brachte wieder Verbote mit sich. Und so war am ende des 18. Jahrhunderts wieder jegliches Glücksspiel verboten.\footnote{Glücksspiel im Laufe der Geschichte}

\subsection{Die Moderne des Glücksspiels}

Die Neuzeit des Glücksspiels dotiert man auf die Entwicklung erster Spielautomaten. Diese erschienen erstmals am ende des 18. Jahrhunderts in Amerika.
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.2\textwidth}
\vspace{-10pt}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Libertybell.png}
\caption{Liberty Bell}
\end{wrapfigure}
Diese Automaten waren von der Funktionsweise rein Mechanisch und boten den Spielern wenig Abwechslung. Nichtsdestotrotz war die Beliebtheit dieser Maschienen groß, was dafür sorgte, dass die Weiterentwicklung dieser Geräte zügig voranging. Dennoch veränderte sich nicht alles. Noch heute sind Nostalgische Elemente aus damaliger Zeit auf den modernen Spielautomaten zu finden. Ein solches ist zum Beispiel der \enquote{Liberty Bell.} Dies war damals wie heute ein Gewinnsymbol. Der grund sie als Gewinnsymbol zu nutzen ist naheliegend. Sie wurde Geläutet als 1752 in Pensylvania die Amerikanische Unabhängigkeitserklärung unterzeichnet worden ist. Automaten waren auch unter dem Namen \enquote{Einarmiger Bandit} bekannt, da sie durch einem Hebel auf der Seite betätigt worden sind, und den Spielern das Geld aus der Tasche gezogen haben. Dies hing mit der Auszalungsrate der Automaten zusammen, die sehr gering war, und so hatten Menschen sehr oft das Gefühl, dass sie bestohlen worden. Aber auch das ist Vergangenheit. Heute haben Automaten Qualitäten, die das Suchtpotenzial und den Spielspaß erhöhen.\footnote{\enquote{Glücksspiel im Laufe der Geschichte}}

\subsection{Glücksspiel heute}

Heutzutage versteht man unter Glücksspiel meist nicht mehr Würfelspiele wie man sie in der Antike gekannt hat. Und stellt man sich als Glücksspiel Kartenspiele und Roulett vor dann irrt man sich. Denn auch Casinos Rutschen aus der Mode. Die Bequemlichkeit der Menschen übertrifft jeden anderen Reiz. So muss man nicht einmal mehr ein Casino besuchen um sich zugang zu Glücksspielen zu erschaffen. Dafür reicht eine herkömmliche Internetverbindung, und schon kann man jegliche Arten von Glücksspielen genießen.\footnote{\enquote{Glücksspiel im Laufe der Geschichte}} Schaut man sich aber vorerst moderne Casinos an, so sieht man überall nur Blinkende Maschienen, hin und wieder einen Blackjack-Tisch, und selten Roulette. Dies Kan man durch die optimalisierung der Software der Glücksspielautomaten erklären. Hierbei spielt mittlerweile auch Künstliche Intelligenz eine große Rolle. Damit beschäftigt sich aber ein anderes Kapitel dieser Arbeit.\footnote{siehe Kapitel ...} In einer digitalisierten Welt übernimmt, auch wie in vielen anderen Branchen, die Online Welt das Sagen. Der Grund dafür ist aber nicht nur der Mensch selbst. Online Casinos bieten mehr auswahl an spielen, und heben eher die Resoursen höhere boni als Landbasierte Casinos anzubieten, da viele Betriebskosten wegfallen.\footnote{der-kultur-blog.de die geschichte des glücksspiels} Dadurch erhöht sich teilweise der Gewinn der Betriebe, andererseits das Entwicklungspotenzial. Denn auch wenn Glücksspielautomaten oder Glücksspiele keine Wissenschaft sind, sitzen Tausende an Psychologie-Experten hinter diesen Konzernen und suchen danach, wie man von den Menschen noch mehr und noch effizienter Geld entziehen kann. Begünstigend kommt dazu, dass Künstliche Intelligenz personalisierte Profile erstellt und die Spiele anpasst. Dazu führend dass das Suchtpotenzial und die Verluste an der Spielerseite steigen.


\section{Die Geschichte der Beschreibung von zufälligen Erreignissen}

Das berechnen des Glücks ist eine sehr junge Wissenschaft. Der erste Mathematiker der sich mit diesem Kapitel der Mathematik auseinandergesetzt hat, war Girolamo Cardano, ein italiäner, der von 1501 bis 1576 gelebt hat. So richtig hat die Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung erst im 17. Jahrhundert seine Bedeutung erlangt mit dem Briefwechsel zwischen Fermat und seinem Schüler, Pascal. Im gegensatz dazu sind Algebra und Geometrie schon Jahrtausende alt, sie waren schon im antiken Griechenland von Philosophen erforscht worden. 

\subsection{Pioniere der Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung}
\label{sec:Pioniere}

Wie schon erwähnt war der erste Mathematiker der sich mit dem Bererchnen des Glücks beschäftigt hat, der italiäner  Girolamo Cardano. 1565 verfasste er das Werk namens \enquote{Liber de Ludo Aleae} (Buch vom Würfelspiel), welches erst fast hundert Jahre später, 1663, veröffentlicht wurde. Dieser Text beschrieb aber nicht alles korrekter Weise, dennoch hatten Cardano und sein Helfer, Niccoló Tartagilia (1506?--1559) wichtige Grundbausteine der Kombinatorik gesetzt, wie die Gesetze zur Addition von Wahrscheinlichkeiten.\footnote{Spektrum.de/rezension}

Galileo Galilei (1564--1642) war der nächste der die Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung geprägt hat. Einen kleinen Teil seiner Werke widmete er sogar dem Würfelwurf und dessen Mathematik.

So richtig zum leben erwäckt wurde die Berechnung von zufälligen Erreignissen aber erst im 17. Jahrhundert, durch Pierre de Fermat (1601--1665) und Blaise Pascal (1623--1662). Blaise Pascal Schrieb eines Tages einen Brief an seinen Lehrer Pierre de Fermat. Dies war der Wahre beginn der Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung. Der Brief behandelte ein Problem, welches Huygens später auch behandelte.\footnote{Handbook of Probability S.4}
\begin{quote}
\itshape \enquote{Ich konnte Ihnen mit der letzten Postsendung nicht alle meine Gedanken bezüglich des Spielabbruchproblems darlegen, und ich habe sogar einigen Widerwillen, dies zu tun, aus Furcht, dass sabei diese wunderbare Übereinstimmung, die zwischen uns war und die mir so Teuer war, sich aufzuheben beginnt; denn ich befürchte, dass wir über diesen Gegenstand verschiedener Ansicht sind. Ich will Ihnen meine Argumente darlegen, und tun Sie mir den Gefallen, mich zu verbessern, wenn ich irre, oder mich zu bestärken, wen ich recht habe. Ich bitte Sie darum inständig und aufrichtig, denn ich werde mich nur im Recht fühlen, wenn sie meiner Ansicht sind.} \footnote{Quelle Brief}
\end{quote}                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Pascals allererste Begegnung mit der Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung war die Lösung der Frage von Antoine Gombaud, Chevalier de Méré, ein damals bekannter Glücksspieler, über die Chancen eine Doppel-sechs beim Würfelspiel zu würfeln, zu diskutieren. Dies ist heute unter dem Namen \enquote{Méré-problem} oder \enquote{Würfelproblem} bekannt.

Ein weiteres Problem, welches als Meilenstein der Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie gesehen werden kann, ist eines das 1656 von Christiaan Huygens (1629--1695) im Buch \enquote{Van Rekeningh in Spelen van Geluck} (Der Wert aller Chancen im Glücksspiel) behandelt wurde. Hierbei ging es um die Verteilung der gewonnenen Summe, bei bestimmten Punkteständen, unter den Spielern. Dieses Werk war das erste welches von Niederländisch auf Latein und Englisch übersetzt worden ist.

Jakob Bernoulli (1654--1704), auch bekannt als Jakob~\rom{1} da es mehrere Jakob Bernoullis gab, schrieb die erste bedeutende Abhandlung der Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie, \enquote{Ars Conjectandi,} welche 2005 von Edith Sylla neu auf Englisch übersetzt publiziert wurde unter dem Namen \enquote{The Art of Conjecturing, together with a Letter to a Friend on Sets in Court Tennis} (Die Kunst des Vermutens, zusammen mit einem Brief an einen Freund über Sätze im Court Tennis), und 1713 posthum veröffentlicht wurde. Das Werk enthielt bemerkenswerte Ergebnisse in Bereich der Kombinatorik, Summen, und Integral im bezug zur Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie. Außerdem ergänzte es werke von Fermat, Pascal, und Huygens. Eine weitere auffällige Eigenschaft der Publikation war der rigorose Beweis des \enquote{Schwachen Gesetzes der Großen Zahlen}: 
\[\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|\bar{X}_n-\mu|>\epsilon)=1\]

Im 18. Jahrhundert wurde das Buch \enquote{The Doctrine of Chances} (Die Lehre von den Wahrscheinlichkeiten) von Abraham De Moivre (1667--1754) publiziert. Damit leistete De Moivre grundlegende Arbeit in bezug zum Problem \enquote{Ruin des Spielers} (das verlieren des Letzten Kapitals und somit die Möglichkeit weiterzuspielen). Sein wichtigstes Ergebnis bestand darin, eine Annäherung an die symmetrische  Binomialverteilung zu finden, die er als eine Annäherung an die Normalverteilung darstellen könnte. Dieses Ergebnis läuft in der modernen Terminologie auf einen Beweis hinaus welcher besagt, dass die symmetrische Binomialverteilung durch die Normalverteilung angenähert werden kann.

Ein weiterer Pionier der Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie war Leonhard Euler (1701--1783), welcher viele seiner Beiträge zur Wahrscheinlichkeitsberechnung, auf einer Untersuchung der Genueser Lotterie basierte. Insbesondere Beschäftigte er sich mit dem Problem der Rencontres, wo Euler zeigen konnte dass die Wahrscheinlichkeit, wenn sich zwei Personen gegenseitig von $1-n$ nummerierte Karten zeigen, dass sie einander gleichzeitig die gleiche Karte zeigen, den Wert $1/e$ annähert wenn $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ ist.

 
\subsection{Das Glück mathematisch beschreiben}
\label{sec:Das_Glück}

Wenn man sagt, dass Glück nicht beeinflussbar ist, wie kann man das dann Mathematisch darstellen? Und kann man damit überhaupt \enquote{klassisch} rechnen?

Bevor man diese Fragen beantworten kann, muss man die Begriffe aus dem Glück mathematisch definieren, beziehungsweise die Alltagsbegriffe in die Sprache der Mathematik übersetzten.

Statt Glück verwendet die Mathematik den Begriff \enquote{Zufall.} Um einen Zufall zu berechnen, rechnet man mit \enquote{Wahrscheinlichkeiten.} Wie viel Chance hat es, dass es morgen regnen wird? Die Menge aller möglichen Ergebnisse ist die Ergebnissmenge 
\[S=\left\{X_1;X_2;...;X_n\right\}\] 
Was in diesem Fall: 
\[S=\left\{S;R\right\}\footnote{Introduction to Probability Models}\] 
ist, $S$ für Sonnenschein und $R$ für Regen. Die Wahrscheinlichkeit für das eintreffen von $R$ beträgt null wen es gar nicht wahrscheinlich ist dass es regnen wird. Ist es aber sicher dass es morgen regnen wird, ist die Wahrscheinlichkeit für das Eintreffen von $R$ eins. Bei einem Münzwurf beträgt die Wahrscheinlichkeit $P(x)=0.5$ für beide Ereignisse, Kopf, wie Zahl. Von einem \enquote{Versuch} redet man dann, wenn man zum Beispiel einen Würfel, oder eine Münze wirft. Man \enquote{testet} die Wahrscheinlichkeit. Bei einem Würfel- oder Münzwurf handelt es sich sogar um einen \enquote{Laplace'schen Versuch}\footnote{Mathebuch 6. Klasse}, da jeder Ausgang des Versuchs gleich wahrscheinlich ist.  Verschiedene Versuche müssen mit verschiedenen Verteilungen berechnet und modelliert werden, da sich Roulett, ein Münzwurf, Lotto oder  Black Jack ganz anders verhalten. Das Ergebnis eines Versuchs ein \enquote{Versuchsausgang} oder \enquote{Ereignis}~$X$. Das heißt, ein Zufallsversuch hat die Wahrscheinlichkeit $P(X_n)$ den einen bestimmten $n$-ten Versuchsausgang zu produzieren. Wobei gilt: 
\[0\leq P(X)\leq1.\]

Versuche haben aber nicht nur ein Ergebnis und dieses Ergebnis eine Wahrscheinlichkeit $P(X)$, sondern auch einen Erwartungswert: 
\[E(X)=\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_n}{n}\] 
Dieser beschreibt das durchschnittliche Ergebnis des Versuchs. Wenn man jetzt einen Würfelwurf als Versuch hernimmt, und einsetzt sieht das dann wie folgt aus: 
\[E(X)=\frac{1+2+3+4+5+6}{6}=3{,}5\] 
Noch einen wichtigen Wert darf man nicht vergessen wenn man mit Wahrscheinlichkeiten rechnet. Dies ist die Varianz. Sie beschriebt wie weit unsere Ergebnisse von unserem Erwartungswert gestreut sind. Die Formel dafür lautet: 
\[\sigma^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}(x_n-\bar{x})^2\] wobei 
\[\sum^n_{i=1}(x_n-\bar{x})^2\] 
die Summe aller Ereignisse minus den Duschschnitt der Ereignisse zum Quadrat ist. Setzt man wieder einen Würfelwurf ein bekommt man folgende Gleichung: 
\[\sigma^2=\frac{\sum^6_{i=1}(x_6-\frac{1+2+3+4+5+6}{6})^2}{6}=\frac{17,5}{6}\approx2,92\] 
Diese Formel nochmal umgeformt bekommt man die Standardabweichung:
\[\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}(x_n-\bar{x})^2}{n}}\] 
Sie beschreiibt nun nicht mehr das Maß der Streuung, sondern die durchschnittliche Abweichung des Ergebnisses vom Erwartungswert. Und wenn man wieder einsetzt sieht man gleich, dass wenn man die Varianz berechnet hat, die Standardabweichung nichts anderes ist als: 
\[\sqrt{\sigma^2}=\sqrt{\frac{\sum^6_{i=1}(x_6-\frac{1+2+3+4+5+6}{6})^2}{6}}=\sqrt{\frac{17,5}{6}}\approx1,71\] 

Um jetzt verschiedene Informationen aus einer bestimmten Datenmenge herauslesen zu können, verwendet man verschiedene Formeln, in der Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie Verteilungen genannt.
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll >{$\displaystyle}l<{$} @{}}
\mc{1}{@{}l}{Verteilung} & \mc{1}{l}{$X$ zählt} & \mc{1}{l}{$P(X)$} \\ 
\midrule
Binomial & Erfolge bei $n$ fixen Versuchen 
& \binom{n}{k}p^x(1-p)^{n-x} \\ \addlinespace
Poisson & Ankünfte in einer fixen Zeitspanne 
& \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!} \\ \addlinespace
Geometrisch & Versuche bis zum ersten Erfolg 
& p(1-p)^{x-1}\\
Negativ-Binomial & Versuche bis zum $k$-ten Erfolg 
& \binom{x-1}{k-1}p^k(1-p)^{x-k} \\ \addlinespace
Hypergeometrisch & Elemente in einer Stichprobe\footnote[56]{Ohne Zurücklegen} 
& \frac{\binom{M}{x}\binom{N-M}{n-x}}{\binom{N}{n}}
\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          \end{center}

\subsection{Entwicklung mathemathischer Methoden}

Ausdrücke wie diese sind das Ergebnis Jahrhunderte langer Arbeit. Einige der Wissenschaftler und Mathematiker, die zur Entwicklung der in Unterkapitel~\ref{sec:Das_Glück} (Das Glück mathematisch beschrieben) wurden im Unterkapitel~\ref{sec:Pioniere} (Pioniere der Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung) schon erwähnt. Hier soll es aber nicht um die Personen gehen, sondern viel eher um die Entwicklung der Mathemathik. Um Rechenwege und Herleitungen der Methoden, die heutzutage in der Wahrscheinlichkeitsberechnung gang und gebe sind.

Girolamo Cardano kam 1565 zum Schluss, dass wenn man eine Chance von $\frac{1}{c}$ hat, dass ein Ereignis eintrift, und $n$ Anzahl an Versuchen durchführt, wird man das Ereignis $\frac{n}{c}$ mal erhalten.

Wärenddessen findet in Frankreich der Briefwechsel zwischen Pascal und Fermat, über das Abgebrochene Spiel Problem, statt. Hierbei handelt es sich um folgende Situation: Man stelle sich vor 2 Spieler:innen spielen einen Würfelspiel. Die Person die höher würfelt gewinnt. Aber das Spiel wird vor Spielende abgebrochen. Wie werden Gewinne verteilt? Wenn der Punktestand 1 zu 1 beträgt werden die Gewinne gleichmäßig verteilt. Steht es 2 zu 2 ist das auch eine gleichmäßige Verteilung. Aber was passiert wenn es 2 zu 1 steht? Die person mit einem Punkt hat auch noch Chancen das Spiel zu gewinnen und somit auch den Einsatz. Die Methode die Pascal nutzt, ist rein logisches Kombinieren. Dabei stellt er sich die verschiedenen Ausgänge der nächsten Runden vor. Wenn die zwei Spieler:innen nur bis 3 punkten gespielt hätten ist es einfach. In der Nebenstehenden Grafik sind die Möglichen Ausgänge dargestellt. 
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3585]{Screenshot_2024-01-05_11-43-18.png}
\end{figure}
Was man sieht sind die möglichen Wege, die zu einem Gewinn der beiden Spieler:innen führen. Folgende sind zu beachten:
\begin{itemize}
 \item Spieler:in 1 gewinnt die nächste Runde, es steht 3 zu 1 und Spieler:in 1 gewinnt den Einsatz
 \item Spieler:in 2 gewinnt die nächste runde, es steht 2 zu 2 und das Spiel wird fortgeführt
 \begin{itemize}
  \item Spieler:in 1 gewinnt die 2. Runde, es steht 3 zu 2 und Spieler:in 1 gewinnt den Einsatz
  \item Spieler:in 2 gewinnt die 2. Runde, es steht 2 zu 3 und Spieler:in 2 gewinnt den Einsatz
 \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
Jetzt muss man nur noch schauen wie wahrscheinlich ist es dass Spieler:in 1, beziehungsweise 2 gewinnt. Dazu nimmt man alle \enquote{günstigen} Ereignisse und dividiert sie durch die \enquote{möglichen} Ereignisse. Sieht dann wie Folgt aus:
\begin{itemize}
 \item Die Wahrscheinlichkeit dass Spieler:in 1 gewinnt:
 \[P(S_1)=\frac{2}{3}\] 
 denn es gab 3 mögliche Wege, sie gewinnt davon bei 2.
 \item Die Wahrscheinlichkeit dass Spieler:in 2 gewinnt:
 \[P(S_2)=\frac{1}{3}\] 
 denn es gab 3 mögliche Wege, sie gewinnt davon bei 1.
\end{itemize}
Auf diese Methode ist man damals aber nicht gekommen. Am ehersten konnte Girolamo Cardano dieses Problem Lösen. Dies findet man in seinem \enquote{Buch vom Würfelspiel.}\footnote{Keith Delvin} Doch woran liegt es, ein mit heutigem Auge so einfaches Problem, Wissenschaftler damals kaum lösen konnten? Dies kann man mit zwei grundsetzlichen Gründen erklären:
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Es war ein völlig neues Konzept, die Zukunft berechnen zu wollen.
 \item Die verwendeten Begrifflichkeiten erschwerten das Verständnis. Anstatt von Wahrscheinlichkeit verwendete man damals \enquote{Zufall} oder \enquote{Anzahl der Gelegenheiten}.\footnote{Keith Delvin 20}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Glücksspiele modellieren}

%\bibliography
\end{document}
```